# Open Local HTML files in Xamarin.Forms Web View NOT in Assets Folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.webview

I am trying to open a multipage HTML web page (i.e. test.html, test.css and test.js) which has been downloaded dynamically (thefore can't use assets) and stored in the apps internal storage (Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory).

The URL I am trying to use is as follows:

file:///data/user/0/com.test/files/HTML/Test.html

However I just get file not found.

```
        var filesToDownload = new string[] { "http://myserver/test/test.html", "http://myserver/test/test.css" };
        var directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "HTML");

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        }

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory); 

        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            foreach (var f in filesToDownload)
            {
                wc.DownloadFile(f, System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)));
            }
        }

        var source = new UrlWebViewSource
        {
            Url = System.IO.Path.Combine("file://" + directory, "Test.html")
        };

        WebView1.Source = source;
```

Comment: What does System.IO.Path.Combine("file://" + directory, "Test.html") resolve to? Are you setting a valid file Url for the html file?

Comment: file:///data/user/0/com.test/files/HTML/Test.html

Comment: After some more googling I've found that the WebView runs with a seperate AppData folder and can't access the main AppData folder.

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you have to make sure:

1 Add the [Xamarin.Essentials NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid) package to each project

2 `http://myserver/test/test.html` and `http://myserver/test/test.css` are existed and accessible.

3 The file name of webview source should be the same with the file name you have written to your storage. Not `Test.html`, but `test.html`

So 
`Url = System.IO.Path.Combine("file://" + directory, "Test.html")` should be modified to

`Url = System.IO.Path.Combine("file://" + directory, "test.html")`